# Error al querer mostrar en un fragment un listado de archivos pdf luego de sus permisos

Tags: listview

Me sale el error porque lo que estoy tratando de hacer es mostrar en un fragment un listado de pdf siempre que cargue pero como soy nuevo me doy cuenta que esta fallando la instancia pero no me doy cuenta como resolver. No me da ningún error el gradle pero al ejecutar comienza la pantalla de bienvenida y cuando va cargar el menú con el fragment da ese error.

## ---Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity> <!-- Aquí llamamos nuestro tema -->

            // al poner el intent-filter para la actividad BienvenidaActivity la hace como principal y es la que se va iniciar primero
        <activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity">
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        </application>
```

### ---Main Activity

### Si saco todo lo de los archivos me abre bien el menu.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv_pdf;

    public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    adaptadorPDF obj_adapter;
    public static int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1;
    boolean bolean_permission;
    File dir;


    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        lv_pdf = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_pdf);

        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

        permission_fn();


    }

    private void permission_fn() {


        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),

            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_PERMISSION);

            }

        } else {

                bolean_permission = true;
                getfile(dir);
                obj_adapter = new adaptadorPDF(getApplicationContext(),fileList);
                lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions,  int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {

            if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                bolean_permission = true;
                getfile(dir);
                obj_adapter = new adaptadorPDF(getApplicationContext(),fileList);
                lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor otorgar el permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
         }
    }

        public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {

            File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

            if (listFile!=null && listFile.length >0) {

                for (int i=0; i<listFile.length;i++) {

                    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

                        getfile(listFile[i]);

                    }
                    else {

                            boolean booleanpdf = false;

                            if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".pdf")){

                                for (int j =0; j<fileList.size();j++) {

                                    if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {

                                        booleanpdf = true;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                  }
                                }

                                if (booleanpdf) {

                                    booleanpdf = false;
                                }
                                else{

                                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                                }
                            }
                     }
                }

            }
            return fileList;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

----Fragment involucrado donde quiero que muestre al abrirse la lista de pdf

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_pdf"
        android:divider="#efefef"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

### ----log de errores cuando quiere arrancar el fragment

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thebitles.smartlibraryreader/com.thebitles.smartlibraryreader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.thebitles.smartlibraryreader.MainActivity.permission_fn(MainActivity.java:107)
        at com.thebitles.smartlibraryreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13043 SIG: 9
Process 13043 terminated.
```

Comment: El problema lo tienes aquí:  `lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);` porque `lv_pdf` es `null`. Y es `null` porque no lo estás inicializando bien al hacer `lv_pdf = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_pdf);`. Esto te pasa porque `listView_pdf` está definido en el fragment y no en MainActivity que es donde intentas obtenerlo.

Comment: muchas gracias entonces para que levante desde el propio fragment deberia instanciar y llamar todo desde el mismo y no desde la actividad?.

Comment: Ahora me paso ese error pero me sale otro que dice: Attempt to read from field android.widget.TextView nombre proyecto.AdaptadorPDF$ViewHolder.tv_filename on a null object reference. Por lo que entiendo es algo con la textView. Sera nulo porque no lo estoy referenciando bien?

Comment: Doy por cerrado porque pude solucionar con tu ayuda.